# How to create a new array with a nested array as specific key value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If have an array like this:

```
let array = [ 
             {hash: "11223344", value: "abc"},
             {hash: "11223344", value: "def"},
             {hash: "22113344", value: "jkl"},
             {hash: "22113344", value: "zyw"},
             {hash: "33221144", value: "omn"},
             {hash: "33221144", value: "xyz"}
];
```

and I wanted to loop through that array and create a new array whereby each each `hash` is only listed once and each `value` that was listed with a given is added to an array at the key value in the object of the single `hash`, like this:

```
let newarray = [ 
             {hash: "11223344", value: ["abc", "def"]},
             {hash: "22113344", value: ["jkl", "zyw"]},
             {hash: "33221144", value: ["omn", "xyz"]},
];
```

How would I get there?

Im thinking its something like

```
array.map((item, i, self) => {
    let newArray =[];
    if(item.hash === newArray.hash){
        newArray.value.concat(item.value)
    } else {
        newArray.concat({hash: item.hash, value: [item.value]})
}
```

but how do I instantiate that array at first in the `value` key?
Is my thinking right on the use of the `Array.prototype.map()`?

**EDIT**: I was asked to explain how this question is different than: [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

In contrast to the link, there is no need to group the results and I dont want to use a library like LoDash. The clarity provided about creating the array in the `value` key also has some worth.

I think the answers here also point out the need to use the index and provides several valid tools, some of which arent provided in the answers in the other questions.  Tools such as `reduce()` and `Set`

Comment: `reduce` would the be right tool.

Comment: is the array sorted by `hash`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Comment: @str, but that uses lodash, Im asking for vanilla js

Comment: @ardev Not all answers require lodash.

Comment: @str but OP requested it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function to return a new array.Inside reduce callback use `findIndex` to find the index of the object where the hash matches. If this hash match then update the `value` array, else create a new object, set it's key and value and push it

```js
let array = [{
    hash: "11223344",
    value: "abc"
  },
  {
    hash: "11223344",
    value: "def"
  },
  {
    hash: "22113344",
    value: "jkl"
  },
  {
    hash: "22113344",
    value: "zyw"
  },
  {
    hash: "33221144",
    value: "omn"
  },
  {
    hash: "33221144",
    value: "xyz"
  }
];

let reducedArray = array.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let getHashIndex = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.hash === curr.hash;
  })
  if (getHashIndex === -1) {
    let obj = {};
    obj.hash = curr.hash;
    obj.value = [];
    obj.value.push(curr.value);
    acc.push(obj)
  } else {
    acc[getHashIndex].value.push(curr.value)

  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(reducedArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get an unique list of hashes, then match each item on the unique set using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let array = [ 
  {hash: "11223344", value: "abc"},
  {hash: "11223344", value: "def"},
  {hash: "22113344", value: "jkl"},
  {hash: "22113344", value: "zyw"},
  {hash: "33221144", value: "omn"},
  {hash: "33221144", value: "xyz"}
];

let a = [...new Set(array.map(i => i.hash))]
  .map(hash => {
    return { hash, values: array.filter(v => v.hash == hash).map(v => v.value) }
  })

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and render the collected items with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
var array = [{ hash: "11223344", value: "abc" }, { hash: "11223344", value: "def" }, { hash: "22113344", value: "jkl" }, { hash: "22113344", value: "zyw" }, { hash: "33221144", value: "omn" }, { hash: "33221144", value: "xyz" }],
    grouped = Array.from(
        array.reduce((map, { hash, value }) =>
            map.set(hash, (map.get(hash) || []).concat(value)), new Map),
        ([hash, value]) => ({ hash, value })
    );
    
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` like below

```js
let array = [ 
   {hash: "11223344", value: "abc"},
   {hash: "11223344", value: "def"},
   {hash: "22113344", value: "jkl"},
   {hash: "22113344", value: "zyw"},
   {hash: "33221144", value: "omn"},
   {hash: "33221144", value: "xyz"}
];

let result = array.reduce((acc, ele) => {
   let index = acc.findIndex(e => e.hash === ele.hash);
   if (index == -1) {
    acc.push({
      hash: ele.hash,
      value: [ele.value]
    })
   } else {
    acc[index].value.push(ele.value);
   }
   return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code where we maintain the index of hash encountered before and insert the value to existing object else insert a new object in the results array.

```js
let data = [{
    hash: "11223344",
    value: "abc"
  },
  {
    hash: "11223344",
    value: "def"
  },
  {
    hash: "22113344",
    value: "jkl"
  },
  {
    hash: "22113344",
    value: "zyw"
  },
  {
    hash: "33221144",
    value: "omn"
  },
  {
    hash: "33221144",
    value: "xyz"
  }
];


function aggregateValues(arr) {
  let hashMap = {};
  let result = [];
  arr.forEach((o) => {
    if (hashMap[o.hash] !== undefined) {
      result[hashMap[o.hash]].value.push(o.value);
    } else {
      hashMap[o.hash] = result.length;
      result.push({
        hash: o.hash,
        value: [o.value]
      });
    }
  })
  return result;
}

console.log(aggregateValues(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a for loop to achieve this:

```
array = [ 
     {hash: "11223344", value: "abc"},
     {hash: "11223344", value: "def"},
     {hash: "22113344", value: "jkl"},
     {hash: "22113344", value: "zyw"},
     {hash: "33221144", value: "omn"},
     {hash: "33221144", value: "xyz"}
];

newArray = []
for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    if (newArray[array[i].hash] == null) {
        newArray[array[i].hash] = [array[i].value];
    } else {
        newArray[array[i].hash].push(array[i].value)
    }
}
console.log(newArray);
```